# Scrolline.js is not scrolling across the page on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery scrolline.js

https://github.com/anthonyly/Scrolline.js

I have created a demo and it works

```js
$.scrolline({
  frontColor: "#6e53e5",
});
```

```css
* {
  white-space: pre-line;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1070228/jquery.scrolline.js"></script>

Lorem ipsum dolor amet synth pickled 90's palo santo. 90's ugh vinyl etsy cloud bread hammock man braid air plant iPhone tote bag selfies. Seitan everyday carry distillery, neutra photo booth chillwave pug cray waistcoat. Cloud bread hella synth chambray. Pop-up humblebrag palo santo, lomo jianbing church-key banh mi subway tile kogi microdosing tousled hoodie. Leggings taiyaki paleo scenester messenger bag hashtag. Pop-up keytar artisan art party sriracha +1 neutra lyft migas.

Woke gochujang farm-to-table pinterest 3 wolf moon fam enamel pin marfa, retro fixie pabst tilde kinfolk. Lyft gastropub single-origin coffee cornhole messenger bag hammock quinoa crucifix narwhal lumbersexual bushwick air plant. Pinterest cornhole godard leggings green juice biodiesel pok pok master cleanse street art try-hard. Locavore mlkshk iceland forage chartreuse cliche. Authentic kitsch kale chips listicle viral crucifix master cleanse vaporware yuccie portland, meh keffiyeh franzen lo-fi. Godard flexitarian cred vice chicharrones mumblecore hot chicken letterpress subway tile paleo lyft air plant synth.

Chartreuse blog prism authentic, scenester bushwick tousled. Locavore kitsch keytar gluten-free unicorn. Literally church-key copper mug chia freegan, chicharrones tousled readymade roof party. Keytar gluten-free meditation humblebrag actually williamsburg viral butcher tbh chartreuse blue bottle meggings direct trade. Sustainable cliche iceland cloud bread seitan. Helvetica adaptogen letterpress humblebrag, williamsburg retro keffiyeh brunch truffaut chartreuse banh mi scenester hoodie. Palo santo sustainable unicorn put a bird on it craft beer offal cold-pressed fashion axe williamsburg vegan tilde sriracha aesthetic.

Pinterest trust fund distillery, deep v tote bag pickled cronut plaid kitsch vice gentrify actually selvage. Cronut letterpress tumblr hammock occupy. Sriracha occupy green juice vape, kale chips truffaut viral umami tote bag typewriter celiac shoreditch vice franzen whatever. Brooklyn beard everyday carry mlkshk synth.

Mumblecore banjo tacos taiyaki XOXO tofu humblebrag mlkshk pitchfork, swag disrupt crucifix quinoa everyday carry. Kombucha leggings organic, bushwick subway tile PBR&B copper mug squid snackwave pabst hell of. Tacos migas stumptown yuccie locavore pop-up iPhone DIY. Sustainable tofu bespoke narwhal. Umami bicycle rights disrupt tumblr semiotics photo booth 90's fixie. Next level af typewriter taxidermy venmo prism hexagon copper mug slow-carb. Pinterest keffiyeh vegan franzen raclette umami brunch kinfolk pok pok normcore.

Keytar chillwave hella affogato, DIY small batch tumeric banjo enamel pin narwhal celiac aesthetic glossier roof party. Pabst taxidermy raw denim authentic, venmo iceland chartreuse waistcoat forage green juice cloud bread pinterest. Gastropub ennui iceland hell of. Locavore copper mug snackwave pinterest +1, chambray migas. Umami pour-over shabby chic jianbing small batch brooklyn crucifix trust fund mixtape craft beer farm-to-table. Fixie mumblecore wayfarers small batch asymmetrical, tilde palo santo knausgaard.

Meggings leggings locavore, mixtape 90's gentrify sustainable pok pok. Listicle stumptown church-key letterpress normcore wayfarers, poke unicorn subway tile affogato. Flannel beard kogi blue bottle typewriter cronut man braid salvia before they sold out tacos. Yr live-edge whatever godard squid venmo DIY. Franzen plaid kombucha VHS selvage waistcoat echo park keffiyeh pickled.

Mixtape salvia iceland, tumblr austin brooklyn beard af tousled swag brunch single-origin coffee everyday carry yuccie. Shoreditch vaporware gluten-free viral, crucifix skateboard heirloom deep v activated charcoal tacos godard ennui asymmetrical +1 succulents. Put a bird on it typewriter intelligentsia live-edge jianbing butcher pug chartreuse hot chicken artisan distillery heirloom pabst vexillologist. Williamsburg vice succulents flexitarian art party kombucha meggings DIY. Mlkshk put a bird on it enamel pin twee, green juice beard truffaut letterpress air plant brooklyn austin four loko drinking vinegar unicorn pabst.

Cardigan fanny pack paleo fingerstache enamel pin activated charcoal, glossier tumblr 3 wolf moon palo santo adaptogen chicharrones. Squid biodiesel enamel pin tumblr paleo af plaid unicorn ramps hexagon mixtape fingerstache letterpress. Air plant fanny pack coloring book live-edge everyday carry kickstarter marfa VHS. Glossier vexillologist wayfarers farm-to-table, celiac blue bottle leggings typewriter authentic kombucha readymade put a bird on it +1. Direct trade viral edison bulb vaporware, helvetica fixie kombucha ramps trust fund drinking vinegar XOXO actually ennui. Ethical irony crucifix, neutra pop-up whatever kombucha brooklyn vaporware lomo pug kickstarter. YOLO 3 wolf moon cray ugh air plant palo santo.

Next level art party poke, everyday carry health goth retro raw denim small batch succulents woke microdosing thundercats actually synth pabst. IPhone keytar bitters paleo flexitarian. Pickled lo-fi typewriter ugh, brooklyn single-origin coffee fanny pack meggings. Ethical man bun brooklyn put a bird on it tote bag. Brunch art party franzen, cornhole echo park tattooed farm-to-table kickstarter williamsburg mixtape disrupt freegan. Pok pok offal edison bulb banh mi. Post-ironic quinoa tbh tumblr.

Oh. You need a little dummy text for your mockup? How quaint.
```

However, when I implement this into Hubspot or my local project, scrolline is not working.

[image]
[image]

There are no console errors.

Comment: Probably is some css overriding your configuration, did you check?

Comment: I'll try removing my CSS file see if that does anything.

Comment: @salesh `overflow: hidden;` seems to be the culprit

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` on `body` was the issue here.